# Need a Fresh pair of Eyes to Work Out the Logic Behind Comparing Values in a Map of Maps

Tags: java, loops, dictionary

## Problem

Data is in the format:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>
```

Which looks something like this:

```
{"MilkyWay": {"FirstStar" : 3, "SecondStar" : 9 .... }, "Andromeda": {"FirstStar" : 10, "SecondStar" : 9 .... } }
```

I want to compare the `Star` values in a quick loop, so I'd like to compare the integer value of `FirstStar` in `MilkyWay` and `Andromeda` and have it return `true` or `false`if the values are the same or not. Since this Map of Maps is huge.

## My Attempt

I'd like to do it something like:

```
//GalaxyMap<String, <Map<String, Integer>>

            for (Map<String, Integer> _starMap : GalaxyMap.values())
            {
                for (String _starKey : _starMap.keySet()){
                    //Can't quite think of the correct logic... and I'm tired...
                }

            }
```

I'd like to keep it as short as possible... I've been staring at this for a while and I'm going in circles with it.

**EDIT**

Outer keys differ, Inner keys are the same

Also since this is a response from a server, I don't know the size it's going to be

Comment: Is there a limit, how many entries do you have in your outer Map?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind - the result if the numbers are the same should be true and if the numbers aren't the same, false

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena - there is no limit on the outersize

Answer (score 1):

Why does this need to be a map. If you're *always* using "FirstStar", "SecondStar" etc, as your keys, then why not make it a list instead..

```
Map<String, List<Integer>>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
public boolean compareGalaxyStar(String galaxyName, String otherGalaxyName, int star) {
    List<Integer> galaxyStars = galaxyMap.get(galaxyName);
    List<Integer> otherGalaxyStars = galaxyMap.get(otherGalaxyName);

    return galaxyStars.get(star) == otherGalaxyStars.get(star);
}
```

***NOTE***: You need to do some validation to make sure the input is correct.

To implement this for all stars, it is not much different.

```
if(galaxyStars.size() == otherGalaxyStars.size()) {
    for(int x = 0; x < galaxyStars.size(); x++) {
        // Perform your comparisons.
        if(galaxyStars.get(x) != otherGalaxyStars.get(x)) {
             // Uh oh, unequal.
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem I'm coming up with is I don't know how many Galaxies I'm being passed, so passing lists into maps via reference makes it quite hard...

Comment: So it's not comparing `two` galaxies. It's comparing `n` galaxies?

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of the inner maps also could differ, you should do something like that:

```
static boolean allStarValuesEqual(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> galaxies) {
    Map<String, Integer> refStars = null;
    for (Map<String, Integer> galaxy : galaxies.values()) {
        if (refStars == null) {
            refStars = galaxy;
        } else {
            for (Entry<String, Integer> currentStar : galaxy.entrySet()) {
                if (!currentStar.getValue().equals(refStars.get(currentStar.getKey()))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below program along with output:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class CompareMapValues {
    private final static String FS = "FirstStar";
    private final static String SS = "SecondStar";
    private final static String MW = "MilkyWay";
    private final static String A = "Andromeda";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map> map = new HashMap>();
        Map innerMap1 = new HashMap();
        innerMap1.put(FS, 3);
        innerMap1.put(SS, 9);
        Map innerMap2 = new HashMap();
        innerMap2.put(FS, 10);
        innerMap2.put(SS, 9);
        map.put(MW, innerMap1);
        map.put(A, innerMap2);
        Set set = map.keySet();
        for(String s: set) {
            Map outerMap = map.get(s);
            Set set2 = map.keySet();
            for(String s2: set2) {
                Map innerMap = map.get(s2);
                if(!s2.equals(s)) {
                    Set set3 = outerMap.keySet();
                    for(String s3: set3) {
                        int i1 = outerMap.get(s3);
                        Set set4 = innerMap.keySet();
                        for(String s4: set4) {
                            int i2 = innerMap.get(s3);
                            if(s3.equals(s4) && i1==i2) {
                                System.out.println("For parent " + s + " for " + s3 + " value is " + i1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//Output:
//For parent Andromeda for SecondStar value is 9
//For parent MilkyWay for SecondStar value is 9
```

Hope this helps.